# Some services in services.msc are not listed with sc query

Tags: windows, service, windows-10, mmc

Recently, my services.msc app has become very unresponsive and slow. Takes a few minutes to just open it.  There are a number of issues with the services that are listed, but for one example I'll use AppFabricCachingService.

AppFabricCachingService is listed in services.msc.  But if I do a

```
sc query AppFabricCachingService
```

I get

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc query AppFabricCachingService
[SC] EnumQueryServicesStatus:OpenService FAILED 1060:
The specified service does not exist as an installed service.
```

The AppFabricCachingService is not listed here in the registry either.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services
```

Any thoughts on how to get the services.msc synced with SC and what is actually on the system?

I am using Windows 10

Comment: Are there other services you're having issues with?  AppFabricCachingService may be unusual - I don't have a client system with that installed, however.  You might also check whether the service shows up in PowerShell when querying via gwmi win32_service |? { $_.Name -imatch "AppFabricCachingService" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, I had previously connected my services.msc to another machine (rather than my local machine). When I changed the connection to the remote machine, I didn't think that it would be sticky and persist after closing and reopening the services.msc app. And enough time passed between reopening services.msc that I completely forgot about that change.

It wasn't until that remote machine was powered down for a few days that services.msc would complain at startup that the remote machine's RPC service was not available and would quit.

Comment: that would explain it!